# laravel resource function works correct but when i use it manualy doesent work

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

i am using `laravel 5` when i use laravel `Route::resource` function in my `route.php` file i can get my model collection inside a parameter of my method like this:

```php
     //**web.php** file

     Route::resource('factors', 'FactorsController');

     //called url localhost:8000/factors/1/edit

     //**FactorsController**

     /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
     public function edit(Request $request, Factor $factor)
     {
         //$factor is a collection of Factor Model that contains id '1' information in factor table

         return view('factors.edit', compact('factor'));
     }
```

it is correct and works but when i make a custom url like this:

```
Route::get('factors/{id}/newEdit', 'FactorsController@newEdit');
```

i can't get the collection inside method parameters and it returns empty collection like this:

```
 //called url localhost:8000/factors/1/newEdit

 1)
 //**FactorsController**

 /**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
 */
 public function newEdit(Request $request, Factor $factor)
 {
     return view('factors.newEdit', compact('factor'));
 }
```

`$factor` is a empty collection of `Factor Model` but i want my selected row in database. when i use that like this works correct:

```
 2)
 //**FactorsController**

 /**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
 */
 public function newEdit(Request $request, $id)
 {
     $factor = Factor::find($id);

     return view('factors.newEdit', compact('factor'));
 }
```

but i don't want to call it like 2 i want to call it like 1

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding),  you should have type-hinted variable names match a route segment name :

```
Route::get('factors/{factor}/newEdit', 'FactorsController@newEdit');
```

Since the `$factor` variable is type-hinted as the `Factor` model and the variable name matches the `{factor}` URI segment, Laravel will automatically inject the model instance that has an ID matching the corresponding value from the request URI.

Comment: get is before resource and route is correct. the problem is that i want my selected factor but it returns empty collection.

Comment: Artisan route:list command... What routes look like?